# Unable to try and install from vmware

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

I'm running windows7 on my PC, i am trying to install ubuntu 13.04 through vmware but i'm unable to complete. Is there any problem with my processor or motherboard which is different for ubuntu or windows? Do ubuntu need any diff supported devices?

Comment: Please provide more details about the problem, what step you cannot get past? What is the error's output?

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to enable running VM's in your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given your hardware specs but Im assuming it will support Ubuntu as it is already running Windows 7.

Here is a link that will guide you to install Ubuntu on VMware

[How to install Ubuntu on VMware](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11287/how-to-run-ubuntu-in-windows-7-with-vmware-player/)

Hope that helps. Still if you get any error then give the details of it.